# Adding XmlSerialser to WebApi in .NET Core 2.2 does not work

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, serialization, webapi, media-type

I wanted to add to my WebAPI (ASP .NET Core) the possibility to work also with XML format. I made configuration according to documentation on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but unfortunately, it does not work in my case. In details, I actually made two things. I added a NuGet package Mircrosoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XML and I also added lines below to  ConfigureServiceMethod

```
    services.AddMvc()
             .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
             .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

After this, when I run the application I receive the error below

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\project_name\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.XmlSerializers.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

As you can see method `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` require `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.XmlSerializers.dll` but inside installed NuGet is only 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.dll` which should be ok because in every documentation is written that this dll is required for using this method. Do you know how to resolve this problem? I didn't find any information on the internet about this dll from exception.

Below is my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
        <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
        <RootNamespace>NameOdProjec.WebApi</RootNamespace>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <OutputPath>..\..\..\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Services.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How *did* you add it? Did you add the package? What does  your csproj look like?

Comment: This is a default .NET Core 2.2 WebAPI Project. I added NuGet using the NuGet package manager.

Comment: I added .csproj to my question now.

Comment: Your project is asp.net core 2.2,why did you add `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)` instead of `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)`?

Comment: Also,which line did you make such error?When I add your package reference to my project.It could not reproduce such issue like yours.

Comment: I use SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1) because it was in MSDN documentation but even if I used compatibility with 2.2 it still does not work.

Comment: I received this "System.Private.CoreLib.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module System.Private.CoreLib.dll" so I don't know which line. I  observed that this exception appear always when I try to use this method ".AddXmlSerializerFormatters();"

Answer (score 0):

It was something wrong with my solution file. When I moved my all projects to the different solution then suddenly everything started working :O